# Displaying the first element of the array/string in the textview and starting the array from it

Tags: android, arrays

I have a code in which i am moving the text in the forward and reverse direction with the help of next and back button. Now the problem i am facing is i need to start by displaying the first element in the string and moving this string forward and reverse from that element. Here is my code

```
    String[] answers = { "red", "green", "blue" };
    private int _position = answers.length - 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.learn_main);

        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(answers[_position]);



        // INITIALIZING OVER
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                if (_position < answers.length - 1) {
                    _position++;
                } else {
                    _position = 0;
                }
                tv.setText(answers[_position]);

            }

        });

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (_position > 0) {
                    _position--;
                } else {
                    _position = answers.length - 1;
                }
                tv.setText(answers[_position]);

            }

        });

    }
}
```

I have tried assigning the value i want to start from in xml, doest help because that my first element is repeating twice.

The following didn't help too

```
tv.setText(answers[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is right, but little wrong. So try this modified one. Hope it will work.

```
String[] answers = { "red", "green", "blue" };
private int _position = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.learn_main);

    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(answers[_position]);



    // INITIALIZING OVER
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            if (_position < answers.length - 1) {
                _position++;
            } else {
                _position = 0;
            }
            tv.setText(answers[_position]);

        }

    });

    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (_position > 0) {
                _position--;
            } else {
                _position = answers.length - 1;
            }
            tv.setText(answers[_position]);

        }

    });

}
```

}

Comment: But the above code does not change text on the back button and the next button moves the array forward from red->green->blue and stops on blue, does not starts again from red like my previous code did.